# Sublime Text 2 multiple selections editing in vintage mode

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there there a way to edit files across multiple selections in vintage mode?

I hit `cmd + D` (this is under a Mac) to select instances of string in the file, but I can't figure out how edit the selections.

This is under Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested this on a Mac, but on Linux using `CTRL-D` puts you in visual mode. When you're in visual mode `c` allows you to change the highlighted text, putting you into insert mode much like vim would.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to figure this out myself. I came to find that simply selecting a word with `Ctrl+D` and then pressing `c` isn't a complete solution. It will only select the first occurrence of a word. In order to select and change them all I have found that I need to execute the following sequence:

- Place the cursor at the beginning of the desired word
- `Ctrl+D` to highlight the word
- `Ctrl+F` to open the `Find` box pre-populated with the desired word
- `Alt+Enter` to select all of the matching words
- `c` to make the changes
- `Esc` to return to COMMAND MODE

There are several posts all over the Internet ([including the documentation on the Sublime Text website](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)) which states that pressing `Alt+F3` will select all of the matching words. This does not work for me on openSUSE/KDE. Pressing `Alt+F3` will instead open the window menu for minimizing, maximizing, etc. In fact, if you hover over the `Find All` button after opening the `Find` box it will display Alt-text indicating `Alt+Enter`.

Comment: alt+enter will select ALL matches and put them in edit mode. it's an alternative to cltr+D which is meant to let you specify which matches you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I just press shift+up/down/right/left, then you will find that you can select whatever you want. It works on Mac sublime 3.